# Not able to run game on emulator (Andengine)

Tags: android, andengine

I'm developing a game using andEngine. Game is running on device,but it is not running on emulator. Game exits and is redirected to home screen. What might be the issue?

**No any Errors in Logcat**.

Comment: Anyway please add the logcat output. Maybe we can find a hint...

Answer (score 8):

It is because of openGPL.ES2 of AndEngine library requires device should have and enable OpenGLES.

You must:

1. Install Android SDK versio >=19 with compatible AVD manager.
2. And config in Eclipse for your Android Virtual Device with **GPU emulation = yes** in Hardware config part on the AVD Manager diaglog. **Or** in run configuration parameter add: **`gpu -on`**