# eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented android andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I am new on Andengine.I added Andengine.jar to my project.I want to draw a rectangle and a line.But emulator(API 15) stopping with a blackscreen.There is not a display

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.andengineilkoyun;

import org.andengine.engine.Engine;
import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.FillResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.primitive.Line;
import org.andengine.entity.primitive.Rectangle;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.Background;
import org.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;


public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity {

    private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH=480;
    private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT=800;
    private Camera kamera;
    private Scene sahne;
    private Engine motor;

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //landscape yerine landscape_fixed yazdım
        //
        kamera=new Camera(0,0,CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        final EngineOptions motorAyarlari=new EngineOptions(true,ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new FillResolutionPolicy(),kamera);
        motorAyarlari.getTouchOptions().setNeedsMultiTouch(true);
        motorAyarlari.getTouchOptions().setTouchEventIntervalMilliseconds(500);
        motor=new Engine(motorAyarlari);

        return motorAyarlari;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateResources(OnCreateResourcesCallback arg0)
            throws Exception {


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback arg0) throws Exception {

        this.motor.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
        this.sahne=new Scene();

        sahne.setBackground(new Background(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f));
        Line cizgi=new Line(20,20,780,20,null);
        Rectangle dikdortgen=new Rectangle(0,0,40,50,motor.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

        this.sahne.attachChild(cizgi);
        this.sahne.attachChild(dikdortgen);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPopulateScene(Scene arg0, OnPopulateSceneCallback arg1)
            throws Exception {


    }

}
```

Error:

```
12-17 04:32:44.780: D/AndEngine(1575): MainActivity.onCreate @(Thread: 'main')
12-17 04:32:45.080: D/AndEngine(1575): MainActivity.onResume @(Thread: 'main')
12-17 04:32:45.160: D/libEGL(1575): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
12-17 04:32:45.200: I/dalvikvm(1575): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-17 04:32:45.241: I/dalvikvm(1575): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-17 04:32:45.250: D/libEGL(1575): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
12-17 04:32:45.250: D/(1575): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9ae0b30, tid 1575
12-17 04:32:45.350: D/libEGL(1575): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
12-17 04:32:45.360: D/libEGL(1575): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
12-17 04:32:45.505: W/EGL_emulation(1575): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-17 04:32:45.522: D/OpenGLRenderer(1575): Enabling debug mode 0
12-17 04:32:45.650: D/(1575): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9a7c0b0, tid 1590
12-17 04:32:45.680: I/dalvikvm(1575): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-17 04:32:45.740: I/dalvikvm(1575): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-17 04:32:46.070: D/AndEngine(1575): VERSION: OpenGL ES 2.0 (3.3.0)
12-17 04:32:46.070: D/AndEngine(1575): RENDERER: Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (GeForce GT 130M/PCIe/SSE2)
12-17 04:32:46.070: D/AndEngine(1575): EGLCONFIG: EGLConfig(Red=5, Green=6, Blue=5, Alpha=0, Depth=24, Stencil=0)
12-17 04:32:46.070: D/AndEngine(1575): EXTENSIONS: GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_vertex_half_float 
12-17 04:32:46.090: D/AndEngine(1575): MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS: 16
12-17 04:32:46.090: D/AndEngine(1575): MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS: 1024
12-17 04:32:46.090: D/AndEngine(1575): MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS: 512
12-17 04:32:46.090: D/AndEngine(1575): MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS: 32
12-17 04:32:46.090: D/AndEngine(1575): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
12-17 04:32:46.090: D/AndEngine(1575): MainActivity.onSurfaceCreated @(Thread: 'GLThread 88')
12-17 04:32:46.090: D/AndEngine(1575): MainActivity.onCreateGame @(Thread: 'GLThread 88')
12-17 04:32:46.121: D/AndEngine(1575): MainActivity.onCreateResources @(Thread: 'GLThread 88')
12-17 04:32:46.121: D/AndEngine(1575): MainActivity.onSurfaceChanged(Width=480,  Height=800) @(Thread: 'GLThread 88')
12-17 04:32:46.230: I/dalvikvm(1575): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-17 04:32:46.240: I/dalvikvm(1575): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: u should extend SimpleBaseGameActivity

Comment: did not work.There are same errors

Comment: can u tell me from where u hv downloaded the extensions of andengine?

Comment: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine.  I downloaded gles2

Comment: what was that?????????????link is not working......

Comment: its working. try again please

Comment: can u show me ur project setup screen shot plz ?

Comment: [IMG]http://i43.tinypic.com/28kr14w.png[/IMG]

Comment: did u added extensions of andengine ????? did u set the library in proprty of ur android example project

Comment: [IMG]http://i43.tinypic.com/ilhsn9.png[/IMG]
I am only added andengine.jar to lib folder and build path.
What is missing?

Comment: when you created your emulator, did you enable the GPU emulation? See this Q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178367/not-able-to-run-game-on-emulator-andengine

Comment: Yes.Use host GPU is checked

Answer (score 0):

kindly find the full setup for andengine [added to my [dropbox]](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/muski72r0cbve4m/eq2BaWXpFq).
    Steps for andengine Setup :

```
Step 1 : First download all the extension i hv attached with this answer.

Step 2 : Import all the projects in Eclipse IDE

Step 3 : Add the library required in example project and othere extension there, just right click the project go to Android option there will be library imported if it show red cross plz remove that and add again as shown below :
 Note : plz note that here all the extends need Andengine project as lib in its project, so all the realted to each other..
```

Your project setup should like this  :

[image]

Comment: thank you so much @Monica for help.I did what you said but project throwed another error.I working solve it.probably problem is not lack of extensions.I will resource